# Is there a class equivalent of custom annotations in java?

Tags: java, annotations

I need to have a set of annotated interfaces corresponding to an enum

For eg:

```
enum Type {
  A,
  B,
  C
}
```

I am using custom annotations to ensure that I don't have to define multiple annotations (There are lot of types in my use case)

```
@interface TypeAnnotation {
  Type value();
}
```

Unfortunately there is nothing I can do to define interfaces like this. Hence, I have to make multiple classes like:-

```
@TypeAnnotation(Type.A)
public interface TypeAInterface {}

@TypeAnnotation(Type.B)
public interface TypeBInterface {}
....
```

I don't really need to define anything inside these interfaces, just need to define the annotated interfaces themselves for use in the framework I am using. Hence, I was looking for the analogue for custom annotations that would save me the boilerplate.

A [generic type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) is a generic class or interface that is parameterized over types. I'm looking for a generic interface that is parameterized over enum values.

Comment: I don't understand the requirement, the problem or the workaround. Can you elaborate please?

Comment: A generic type is a generic class or interface that is parameterized over types. I'm looking for a generic interface that is parameterized over enum values instead.

Comment: Ok, I kinda understand what you want, if not why you want it. The problem now is obvious: there's no such thing as parameterizing over enum values. So there's the annotation approach; what's wrong with that? Also, I still have no idea what `TypeAnnotation` is doing here.

Comment: Thanks. I should have figured as much.